# how to load an application into RAM, without launching that app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-memory

I want load a group of applications into RAM, without launching them. When i am loading that applications into RAM, user should be unaware of them.

I tried with following code:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);
    LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Above code starting the application and brought that application into front. But i don't want that application to be brought to front.

Comment: You have to use only service in your application and start this service on boot completion.

Comment: @ManishAndroid Please note that as of Android 3.0, if you have only a service with no activities, the service will never be started because Android will NOT deliver the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast intent to applications that are in a `STOPPED` state.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it via a `Service`. Please read up on `Android` documentation.

`Service/Activity/BroadcastReceivers` are launched with `Intents`.
`Activity` will be shown in the foreground.
`Service` will run in background until it is stopped by `Android OS` or developer.
`BroadcastReceiver` will run for max 10 seconds and will be stopped.

Comment: Small clarification to my question:
I want to launch main activity of other third party applications from my application. But those applications should not brought to front. Can i load those applications into RAM, without launching.

Comment: An Activity is always launched to the foreground, if it goes to the background it is paused. So I have no clue what you want to do in an Activity which is not viable.

Comment: Activity manager service loads some set of applications (contacts,calendar etc) into RAM, immediately when booting was over. While loading those applications, user is not aware of them. Like that i want to load a set of applications into RAM in the background.

Comment: These are System Service, which are not 'normal' APKs. You should create them and add them to the Android OASP and build Android and flash your device.